# Dynamic method in c#

Tags: c#

I have many labels on the form, and every label invokes same method with different argument(which belongs to label text/name). Here is the code:

```
    //"res" is an array
    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                       
        checkresult(res[0]);
    }

    private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
        checkresult(res[1]);
    }

    private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        checkresult(res[2]);
    }

    private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        checkresult(res[3]);
    }

    private void label5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkresult(res[4]);
    }

    private void label6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkresult(res[5]);
    }

    private void label7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkresult(res[6]);
    }

    private void label8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkresult(res[7]);
    }

    private void label9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkresult(res[8]);
    }
```

I just want to precise my code by defining only one method for all labels. How can i do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pseudocode may look like this:

```
label1.Click += label_Click(object sender, EventArgs e); 
label2.Click += label_Click(object sender, EventArgs e);//SAME HANDLER
label3.Click += label_Click(object sender, EventArgs e);//SAME HANDLER
....
```

and after

```
private void label_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(sender == label1)
      checkresult(res[0]);
    else if(sender == label2)
      checkresult(res[1]);
   ... 
   ...
}
```

Comment: At least on `CommandEventArgs` you have `CommandArgument` which would lead to much more clean code. Maybe that doesn't work on `Label` though.

Comment: I know this answer works, but i think that daryal's solution is more usable as it doesn't require editing the handler if you add more labels. That's not to say this isn't great too : )

Comment: @Shane.C: it assuems that label's index is *always* in relation to the index of the elemtn to pick fropm array, wich may not be *always* . What if you refactor your code, and change names of the labels ? With refactoring, my solution will still work.

Answer (score 3):

First let all of your labels use the same `Label_Click` event.

```
private void Label_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label temp = sender as Label;
    if (temp != null)
    {
        string labelName = temp.Name;
        string labelId = labelName.Substring(5, labelName.Length);
        int id = int.Parse(labelId) - 1;
        checkresult(res[id]);
    }                
}
```

Comment: This is also a nice solution, but for this question, that was perfect. Thanks for answering :)

Comment: I'd say this was a great solution  : ) Means you don't have to edit the handler if you add more labels.

Answer (score 1):

You could set anonymous delegates in when you make the event handler

```
label1.Click += (s,e) => {checkresult(res[0]); };
label2.Click += (s,e) => {checkresult(res[1]); };
label3.Click += (s,e) => {checkresult(res[2]); };
```

Answer (score 0):

In WinForms, set your Index to Tag of Label and set each OnClick event to same EventHandler

```
 private void lbl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      checkresult(res[Convert.ToInt32((sender as Label).Tag)]);
 }
```